# Is there a way to use Xamarin code in a Java Android app or in an Obj-C iOS app?

Tags: java, android, ios, xamarin

Pondering the opportunity of writing some libraries in Xamarin rather than having Android and iOS versions.

However, these libraries would be used in third party applications, some of which may be written in Java.

Is it possible to write a Xamarin library in a way that allows it to be integrated in a Java application?

(Same question goes for iOS?)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I just started to look into Xamarin, so I am looking into PCL and Library Projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot.  Xamarin allows you to consume native libraries via bindings, but you cannot consume Xamarin libraries from native code.

Comment: That is what I feared. Do you have an explicit source to back that statement?